# How to create progress bar for copying process in python Gtk

Tags: linux, python-3.x, gtk, glade

I want to create a simple module for my project. That copy files from one host to another host. I have tried that copying part of log files(/var/log) from one host to my server connected in LAN. But it shows the process running on terminal. I want to do it on progress bar while copying the files. So please anybody can help me!

Comment: does your code implement the transfer itself or just invokes shell commands to execute the transfer? You have means to check the progress percentage or you just need an activity indicator/mode (or spinner). Does the transfer occurs asynchronously?

Comment: I have used a simple shell script for copying log files. which is like this.      #!/bin/bash                                                                                               s="/var/log"                                                                                                BACKUPFILE=script.backup.`date+%F`.tar.gz                                           rsync -chavzP --stats root@ipaddr     I want to show this activity of copying on progress bar with percentage

Comment: Can You plz help me out with this @JoséFonte

Comment: Well, if you use a shell script it will be trickier to get the progress. Seems that rsync has a --progress flag (read 'man rsync') which dumps to the console some information that you can then parse. On the application you can get this information via popen (e.g.) and then parse the output and try to update the GUI. The other problem you face is that if you use this solution it will probably block the UI so you must use async methods or threads on the transfer and get the UI updated at regular intervals (e.g.). There are some aproaches but it ain't trivial.

Comment: Can you give me the detailed explained or if you have code then can you share with me @JoséFonte

Comment: can you post some code of what you are doing, would help.

Comment: @JoséFonte I have added another question on same topic plz go through that